# How to test if Python is running from a virtualenv during package installation

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a Python software which includes a configuration file and a manpage. To install these, I have the following line in my `setup.py` (as described on http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files):

```
data_files = [('/etc/foo', ['foo.conf']), ('/usr/share/man/man1', ['foo.1'])]
```

This works just fine when I want to install the software as root with `python setup.py install`, but of course fails in a virtualenv, as the user is not permitted to write to `/etc` and `/usr/share/man`.

What is the best practice to fix that? Check for `VIRTUAL_ENV` in the current environment and just not install those files at all? The software will look for `foo.conf` in the local directory, so that should be no problem. The user would miss the manpage, but there is no sane way to install it anyways, as `man` won't look for it anywhere near the virtualenv.

Comment: I don't have a full answer to your question, but checking for VIRTUAL_ENV is not dependable since one can also explicitly run the "python" binary from the virtualenv's bin directory to get the same effect.

Comment: @MartinAtkins sure? The actual binary is identical: `md5sum /tmp/bar/bin/python /usr/bin/python
b35da8492c4ddb3e3413411e574db63a  /tmp/bar/bin/python
b35da8492c4ddb3e3413411e574db63a  /usr/bin/python`. 
And my understanding was, that I *have* to activate the env by sourcing `bin/activate`.

Comment: No you do not have to activate the env. You can `cd /path/to/virtualenv` then `bin/python` just fine.

Comment: The `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable is not used by the Python binary itself; `VIRTUAL_ENV=/path/to/virtualenv /usr/bin/python` does not work to enable it, for example.

Comment: The most important thing the "activate" script does is set the PATH environment variable so that when you run "python" you'll get the one in the virtualenv; the VIRTUAL_ENV variable is really only there for virtualenv's own recordkeeping. The trick to virtualenv is that python determines its prefix by looking at the directory above where its binary is installed, so in /usr/bin it'd be /usr but in your virtualenv it's the environment root.

Comment: In addition to what Martin wrote, above, the other trick is that Python knows both where it's being _run from_ **and** where it's _actually installed to_. It uses `sys.base_prefix` to find the standard library (which isn't relocated into a venv), and it uses `sys.prefix` to find the `site-packages` directory (which will be inside the venv). `sys.base_prefix` is relative to the actual `os.path.realpath()` of the Python binary, whereas `sys.prefix` is relative to the directory where the executable was launched from (the venv's `bin/` directory, if in a venv).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**CAUTION:** I originally wrote this answer many years ago, and so was discussing the behavior of a now-very-old version of virtualenv and working with Python 2.7, rather than Python 3.

I don't know to what extent the answer below remains accurate for current versions of Python and virtualenv. I expect that at least parts of it are misleading when considering the current behavior of this software.

---

Ultimately it seems that your question is really about how to detect whether the running Python is in a virtualenv. To get to the bottom of this we must understand how `virtualenv` actually works.

When you run the `activate` script inside a virtualenv, it does two things:

- it updates the `PATH` environment variable to include the `bin` directory from the virtualenv, so that when you run `python` the binary from the virtualenv will run.
- it sets a variable `VIRTUAL_ENV` so that the activate script itself can keep track of the activation.

It's perfectly acceptable to directly run the `python` from the virtualenv, and at runtime `python` does not use the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable at all. Instead, it determines the directory containing the running `python`binary and uses the parent directory as its "prefix".

You can determine the system's prefix by importing the `sys` module and consulting `sys.prefix`. However, it would be a bad idea to depend on the value of this when a virtualenv is *not* activated because this is a build-time setting for Python that can easily be customized, and it will definitely vary between platforms.

However, Python does have *one* slight runtime difference when it runs from a virtualenv prefix vs. its compiled-in prefix: the `sys` package has an additional variable `real_prefix` that returns the prefix that is compiled into the Python binary. Therefore one could use this to recognize that Python is running in a non-default location, which is reasonably likely to mean it's running from a virtualenv:

```
import sys

if getattr(sys, "real_prefix", None) is not None:
    print "Maybe in a virtualenv"
else:
    print "Probably not in a virtualenv"
```

However, even this is not an exact science. All this really tells you is that the python binary is not at the location specified at compile time. It does not tell you whether the current user has access to write to `/usr/share/man` -- there are some (possibly edge) cases where this won't give you the right answer:

- If the user has compiled his own Python from source in his home directory and its compiled prefix is `/home/johnd/local-python` then `real_prefix` won't be set but the user still has write access to his Python `lib` directory, and probably *not* write access to `/etc` or `/usr/share/man`
- Likewise, on some systems the administrator may have granted group-write privileges on `/usr/lib/python2.7` to a certain group of app developers so that they can install Python modules, but not have granted them write access to other system files.

So I think in the end the best you can do is a heuristic and it may be better to instead just avoid using absolute paths in `data_files` for any module you expect to be used inside a virtualenv. A compromise might be to simply split your module into two distributions, one representing the localizable source files and another representing the system-wide configuration to make it run. The latter can depend on the former so that users can still easily install it, but those using `virtualenv` have the option of using the other former directly.

Answer (score 1):

Many Python users erroneously believe that it's the modifications to `$PATH` performed by the `bin/activate` script, that define a virtual env. But that's not true — the `activate` script is a convenience that has no effect on Python at all, it merely configures your environment to *access* the venv more easily.

A Python virtual environment is defined by the changes that occur to **`sys.path`** when running inside it, and by Python's automatic discovery of the library dir relative to the filesystem location of the `python[3[.n]]` interpreter executable. All of the process environment variables, including `$PATH` and `$VIRTUAL_ENV`, are irrelevant to the virtual environment within Python. Any detection that uses environment variables is really just a check for whether the `activate` script has been run. And as Martin has tried to point out, the `activate` script is *not* a prerequisite for running within a venv.

If you have a virtual environment at `/home/me/my_venv/`, sourcing `/home/me/my_venv/bin/activate` and then running `python3` will get you a REPL that's running inside that virtual environment. But **so will running `/home/me/my_venv/bin/python3` WITHOUT sourcing `activate`**. The `$PATH` will be different and `$VIRTUAL_ENV` won't be set, but `sys.path` will be identical using either method. (Try it and see!)

So, the key to detecting a venv lies with how `sys.path` changes when the interpreter is run from a location other than its installed path, and that starts with the modified `sys.prefix`.

`sys.real_prefix` is something the `virtualenv` package used to set. It [caused problems](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1095), ironically because `venv` failed to detect that it was running inside a `virtualenv`, so `virtualenv` dropped `sys.real_prefix` with its [v20 rewrite](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1366). In fact, as of v20 `virtualenv` creates its virtual environment ***using*** the standard library `venv` module if it's available. (Which it is, in all currently supported Python versions.)

So, for all currently-supported Python releases (3.7–3.11), the following will effectively detect a virtual environment without relying on `$PATH` or `$VIRTUAL_ENV`. (I kept the `sys.real_prefix` check, even though it should rarely succeed and would indicate a very out-of-date `virtualenv` package.)

```py
def in_venv() -> bool:
    """Determine whether Python is running from a venv."""
    import sys
    if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
        return True
    pfx = getattr(sys, 'base_prefix', sys.prefix)
    return pfx != sys.prefix
```

That still won't detect a very specific type of "virtual" environment, though: A vendored Python interpreter distribution that's been installed completely separate from the system installation(s). Those won't register as virtual environments, because the `sys.base_prefix` will be the same as `sys.prefix` —they'll *both* point to the runtime's install directory.

For example, ActiveState Python on Windows will install a vendored interpreter binary into each project instance that's created on the system. That runtime may have a `sys.prefix` like `c:\users\$name\appdata\local\activestate\cache\$random`, and `sys.base_prefix` will be the same. Some Node.js packages do similar things with vendored Python installations.

In these situations, `sys.path` will also be entirely located under the `sys.prefix` path, making the installation not technically a *virtual* environment at all. It's merely a non-system, vendored Python runtime environment with no connection to or dependencies on any system runtime. Those environments are much trickier to reliably detect, and coding assumptions about what to do in those conditions is a much dicier prospect.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple answer I've found for the question as it is, is to run:

```
pip -V # (Uppercase V)
```

Comment: The problem is, `pip -V` (or even if you skip the command alias and use the recommended `python3 -m pip -V` instead) is yet another method that's really detecting **whether you've run the venv's `bin/activate` script**. If you haven't sourced `bin/activate`, running `pip -V` will show the path to your system `pip`. (Or user `pip`. Outside of a venv I get `pip 23.3.2 from $HOME/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip (python 3.12)`.) Also, the question was how `setup.py` code can detect that it's running in a venv, which this doesn't help with at all.

Answer (score 0):

Narrowing the question to its title only:

> ***"How to test if Python is running from a virtualenv during package installation"***

Being more than 7 years old, the accepted answer did not work for me (`python 3.6.9` on Ubuntu 18.04).

It failed to detect I'm in a virtualenv (activated and being used) when I was. More specifically, `getattr(sys, "real_prefix", None)` returned `"/usr"` and (wrongly) concluded I'm not running from a virtual-env.

The alternative solution as suggested in the question itself worked fine `(1)`.
It is simple & straightforward, despite objections above that it might be unreliable under non-common situations.

Save to a file `is-in-venv` and make it executable, and it can be called from a shell, `if is-in-venv; then ...; else ...; fi`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys

venvdir = os.getenv('VIRTUAL_ENV')

if venvdir and os.path.isdir(venvdir):
    print("python3 virtual-env detected: %s" % venvdir)
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print("python3 not in a virtual env")
    sys.exit(1)
```

`(1)` *For the benefit of potential future users looking for a working solution to the title as written, for python3, circa 2020.*

Comment: Well, that's just silly. If you're going to use the _shell_ to determine whether `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set in the environment, you certainly don't need Python to decide that for you. Just use `if [ "x$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "x" ]`!

Comment: Or, if you still want to perform the directory test, just `if [ -d "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]` (which will DTRT and test false if `$VIRTUAL_ENV` is unset in the environment).

Comment: The OP question was "how to test if python is running from a virtualenv ..." so python code to do the check is appropriately addressing the question.  The only reason I added the shebang and `sys.exit()` to run this from a shell is to make the code full self-contained and reproducible as a unit, in addition to being able to call it directly from python.  Obviously you can check the existence of a env var from any language supporting it. Cheers.